# How to change/remove class when close SlideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I want to remove the *ativo* class from *liToggle* when close my SlideToggle.
I've tried to use is(":hidden") and the ELSE statement, but doesn't work.

How can i do this?

```
$("aside #menu-busca ul > li a").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#"){

        var ulToggle = $(this).parent().children("ul");
        var liToggle = $(this).parent();
        ulToggle.slideToggle("slow");

        if (ulToggle.is(":visible")){
            $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
        }
        // * Here?
        else {
            $(liToggle).removeClass("ativo");
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

I have a codepen here too... can be useful: http://codepen.io/maykelesser/pen/RKdgvY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait till `slideToggle()` animation actually completes to determine whether it's `:visible` or not.

You can pass a callback:

```
var ulToggle = $(this).parent().children("ul");
var liToggle = $(this).parent();

ulToggle.slideToggle("slow", function() {
    if (ulToggle.is(":visible")){
        $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
    }
    else {
        $(liToggle).removeClass("ativo");
    }
});

return false;
```

Or use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
ulToggle.slideToggle("slow").promise().then(function() {
    if (ulToggle.is(":visible")){
        $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
    }
    else {
        $(liToggle).removeClass("ativo");
    }
});
```

Also, you can avoid the entire `if` clause using:

```
$(liToggle).toggleClass("ativo", ulToggle.is(":visible"));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you toggle the ul you need to use a callback. Because when you making slide toggle it take some time. See the **[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyRyNp)**.

```
ulToggle.slideToggle("slow", function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
    }
});
```

Or Use jquery `$.when`

```
$.when(ulToggle.slideToggle("slow")).then(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("aside #menu-busca ul > li a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {

      var ulToggle = $(this).parent().children("ul");
      var liToggle = $(this).parent();
      ulToggle.slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if (ulToggle.is(":visible")) {
          liToggle.addClass("ativo");
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu-busca ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu-busca ul li.ativo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#menu-busca ul li.ativo ul {
  display: block;
}

.ativo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<aside>
  <div id="menu-busca">
    <ul>
      <li class="ativo"><a href="#">Categoria 01</a>
        <ul>
          <li>SubCat01-01</li>
          <li>SubCat01-02</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Categoria 02</a>
        <ul>
          <li>SubCat02-01</li>
          <li>SubCat02-02</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or create a general class for all `ul` that they are collapsible/expandable and when click on a link, close all `ul` with that class except the clicked one:

HTML

```
<aside>
  <div id="menu-busca">
    <ul>
      <li class="ativo"><a href="#">Categoria 01</a>
        <ul class="all">
          <li>SubCat01-01</li>
          <li>SubCat01-02</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Categoria 02</a>
      <ul class="all">
          <li>SubCat02-01</li>
          <li>SubCat02-02</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

and js

```
$(function() {  
  $("aside #menu-busca ul > li a").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#"){
$(".all").not(this).slideUp("slow");
        var ulToggle = $(this).parent().children("ul");
        var liToggle = $(this).parent();
        ulToggle.slideToggle("slow");

        // * Se estiver aberto
        if (ulToggle.is(":visible")){
            $(liToggle).addClass("ativo");
        }

        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKOKWV